# How to send data to default fragment using navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer. I want to send array list to default fragment. but i check that in my default fragment it always shows null. Following is my code for navigation drawer and default fragment. in my fragment i am receiving data from main activity can any one help me to solve this?

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fcm_id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        prodcounter=session.usercounter();
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);


        Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
        bundles.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "btn_click");
        bundles.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Next Activity");
        bundles.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundles);
        //Logs an app event.
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundles);

        //Sets whether analytics collection is enabled for this app on this device.
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

        //Sets the minimum engagement time required before starting a session. The default value is 10000 (10 seconds). Let's make it 20 seconds just for the fun
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(20000);

        //Sets the duration of inactivity that terminates the current session. The default value is 1800000 (30 minutes).
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setSessionTimeoutDuration(500);
        System.out.println("Parent Counter : " + prodcounter);
      //  id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        userid = session.userID();
        System.out.println("Parent ID : " + userid);

        userd=Long.parseLong(userid);
        prefss = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefimmg = prefss.getString("prefimgg", null);
        prefnmms = prefss.getString("prefnmss", null);
        System.out.println("Parent Activity Promocode"+promocodestore+prefimmg+prefnmms);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        cartcounter = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textOne);
        noticounter=(TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.texttwo);
        if(prodcounter==null || prodcounter.equals("0"))
        {
            cartcounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("HomeFrag Counter null:");
        }
        else
        {
            cartcounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("HomeFrag Counter notnull:");
            cartcounter.setText(" "+prodcounter+" ");
        }
        cartcounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(prodcounter==null || prodcounter.equals("0"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Shopping Cart is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    BuyNowActivity llf = new BuyNowActivity();
                    llf.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            }
        });
        imgserach=(ImageView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imagesearch);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();


        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
      //  mSelectedItemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = ExpandList.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ExpandList.setIndicatorBounds(ExpandList.getRight() - 40, ExpandList.getWidth());
            }
        });

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
        headerimg=(ImageView)listHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.filmIcon);
        headertxt=(TextView)listHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.website);
        ExpandList.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        if(prefimmg!=null)
        {
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(prefimmg)
                    .error(com.bpc.us.project.R.drawable.nopreview )
                    .placeholder(com.bpc.us.project.R.drawable.progress_animation)
                    .into(headerimg);
        }
        else
        {
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.user)
                    .error(com.bpc.us.project.R.drawable.nopreview )
                    .placeholder(com.bpc.us.project.R.drawable.progress_animation)
                    .into(headerimg);
        }
        if(prefnmms!=null)
        {
            headertxt.setText(prefnmms);
        }
        else
        {
            headertxt.setText("My Account");
        }

     //   mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        Drawerdata();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){

            if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ForFBGOOGLE"))
            {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FBGoogleAddress llf = new FBGoogleAddress();
                llf.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ForDelieveringProduct"))
            {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                DelieveringProduct llf = new DelieveringProduct();
                llf.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ForOrderActivity"))
            {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                OrderActivity llf = new OrderActivity();
                llf.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromskips"))
            {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("imagesliderlist", imagesliderlist);
                bundle.putString("offerBandText", offerBandText);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                 currentFragment = new HomeFragments();
                currentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, currentFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("forfailure"))
            {
                placeorderlists =  (ArrayList<PlaceOrderModel>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeorderitems");
                // placeordershippinglists =  (ArrayList<PlaceorderShipping>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeordershippingitems");
                // placeorderbillinglists =  (ArrayList<Placeorderbilling>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeorderbillingitems");

                subtotal=getIntent().getStringExtra("subtotal");
                discount=getIntent().getStringExtra("discount");
                shipVal=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipVal");
                shippingMethod=getIntent().getStringExtra("shippingMethod");
                paidAmount=getIntent().getStringExtra("paidAmount");
                orderid=getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
                shipid=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipid");
                shiptype=getIntent().getStringExtra("shiptypes");

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("placeorderitems", placeorderlists);
                bundle.putString("subtotal", subtotal);
                bundle.putString("discount", discount);
                bundle.putString("shipVal", shipVal);
                bundle.putString("paidAmount", paidAmount);
                bundle.putString("orderid", orderid);
                bundle.putString("shippingMethod", shippingMethod);
                bundle.putString("shipid", shipid);
                bundle.putString("shiptypes", shiptype);
                // FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                PaymentFailure llf = new PaymentFailure();
                llf.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }

            else if(getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("forsuccess"))
            {
                placeorderlists =  (ArrayList<PlaceOrderModel>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeorderitems");
                // placeordershippinglists =  (ArrayList<PlaceorderShipping>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeordershippingitems");
                // placeorderbillinglists =  (ArrayList<Placeorderbilling>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("placeorderbillingitems");

                orderid=getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
                orderdate=getIntent().getStringExtra("orderdate");
                total=getIntent().getStringExtra("total");
                subtotal=getIntent().getStringExtra("subtotal");
                discount=getIntent().getStringExtra("discount");
                shipVal=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipVal");
                shippingMethod=getIntent().getStringExtra("shippingMethod");
                paidAmount=getIntent().getStringExtra("paidAmount");
                cardNumber=getIntent().getStringExtra("cardNumber");
                billfirstname=getIntent().getStringExtra("billfname");
                billlname=getIntent().getStringExtra("billlname");
                billadd1=getIntent().getStringExtra("billadd1");
                billadd2=getIntent().getStringExtra("billadd2");
                billcity=getIntent().getStringExtra("billcity");
                billstate=getIntent().getStringExtra("billstate");
                billcountry=getIntent().getStringExtra("billcountry");
                billzip=getIntent().getStringExtra("billzip");
                billphone=getIntent().getStringExtra("billphone");
                shipfname=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipfname");
                shiplname=getIntent().getStringExtra("shiplname");
                shipadd1=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipadd1");
                shipadd2=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipadd2");
                shipcity=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipcity");
                shipstate=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipstate");
                shipcountry=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipcountry");
                shipzip=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipzip");
                shipphone=getIntent().getStringExtra("shipphone");

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("placeorderitems", placeorderlists);
                bundle.putString("orderid", orderid);
                bundle.putString("orderdate", orderdate);
                bundle.putString("total", total);
                bundle.putString("subtotal", subtotal);
                bundle.putString("discount", discount);
                bundle.putString("shippingMethod", shippingMethod);
                bundle.putString("shipVal", shipVal);
                bundle.putString("paidAmount", paidAmount);
                bundle.putString("cardNumber", cardNumber);
                bundle.putString("billfname", billfirstname);
                bundle.putString("billlname", billlname);
                bundle.putString("billadd1", billadd1);
                bundle.putString("billadd2", billadd2);
                bundle.putString("billcity", billcity);
                bundle.putString("billstate", billstate);
                bundle.putString("billcountry", billcountry);
                bundle.putString("billzip", billzip);
                bundle.putString("billphone", billphone);
                bundle.putString("shipfname", shipfname);
                bundle.putString("shiplname", shiplname);
                bundle.putString("shipadd1", shipadd1);
                bundle.putString("shipadd2", shipadd2);
                bundle.putString("shipcity", shipcity);
                bundle.putString("shipstate", shipstate);
                bundle.putString("shipcountry", shipcountry);
                bundle.putString("shipzip", shipzip);
                bundle.putString("shipphone", shipphone);
                // FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                PaymentSuccessful llf = new PaymentSuccessful();
                llf.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else
            {
                if (savedInstanceState == null){
                   /*currentFragment = new HomeFragments();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, currentFragment).commit();*/

                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("imagesliderlist", imagesliderlist);
                    bundle.putString("offerBandText", offerBandText);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    currentFragment = new HomeFragments();
                    currentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, currentFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        }
        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();
        listHeaderView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(userd > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Positive");
                   /* Intent intent=new Intent(ParentActivity.this,OrderActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    // FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    OrderActivity llf = new OrderActivity();
                    llf.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.bpc.us.project.R.id.frame_container, llf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(ExpandList);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Negative");
                    // String skipsid=String.valueOf(userd);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login_Page.class);
           /* intent.putExtra("proceedtocheckoutid",skipsid);
            intent.putExtra("isCheckOut",true);*/
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });

        //GetNotification();

    }
```

HomeFragment

```
 sliderimagelist =  (ArrayList<ImagesliderModel>)getArguments().getSerializable("imagesliderlist");

        offerBandText=getArguments().getString("offerBandText");

        System.out.println("IMAGELISTSIZE"+sliderimagelist+offerBandText);
```

Comment: You are not adding value to the imagesliderlist.

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: I mean: imagesliderlist.add("some content");

Comment: my arraylist is filled in Drawerdata function.

Comment: @SatanPandeya see this https://pastebin.com/DR1i6tQN

Comment: did you check @SatanPandeya